# Allow Users Download a PHP page as JPEG

Tags: php, image

I have a PHP page which creates a JPEG using GET parameters. I want to allow users to be able to download that page's output as JPEG file. How can i do that?

Comment: Have you asked them to try hitting `Ctrl + S`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very basic:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile('cutepuppies.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

echo the output as usual from php, but make sure you send some the content type header for jpeg before any other output.

```
<?php header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); ?>
```

Comment: You do not need to put newlines in the call to `header`.  In fact, they're actively filtered out in modern PHP versions to help mitigate header injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Set your [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php):

```
// Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

Answer (score 1):

At minimum set the Content-Type header -

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

One way is to utilize the imagejpeg function -

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php